# Can I create directories in Windows by unix shell script?

Tags: php, linux, windows, shell

I am developing a small web project for my own learning. The functionality is as follows:
There is one php file which calls one shell script to create folders at a location specified by the user. I have achieved this functionality to work in my Linux machine. Now the question is can I achieve the same functionality in a Windows machine? The confusion here is that the shell script is interpreted only by Linux machines so is it possible to get the same mechanism to work in Windows as well? (The core of the shell script is that it runs a mkdir command which is not identified by windows)

Comment: There is an mkdir php function also. Does it fit to your needs?

Comment: What Errors you got for mkdir() in windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in 3 ways:

1. Translate unix shell script to Windos compatible script e.g. DOS or VBS
2. Install an Unix interpreter like cygwin on Windows and run your script
3. Don't use shell script and do it via PHP itself

**My preference is for option 3 since that makes your PHP script platform agnostic.**

Comment: Thanks @anubhava..I agree with your points. But the thing is I am also having a couple of other commands in shell script like ls, wget whose functionality is not provided by php-core.

Comment: Even wget can be ported over to PHP using built it PHP functions. But you can use cygwin to use script as is.

Comment: So are you saying that when I host this on a domain, I should also get cygwin installed in that? Please correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: Yes installing cygwin is not a big deal, it is freely available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use samba or CIFS  to mount the remote windows shared directory to linux machine and then run your php script with mkdir command. Once you create the directory using mkdir on samba or CIFS share it would get reflected in windows too.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-mount-remote-windows-partition-windows-share-under-linux.html

The above link would show you how you can do it.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker